# microsoft interop excel get_Range

Tags: c#, excel, interop

I've developed an Asynchronous socket method in order to receive a text from other application and show it in an Excel worksheet.
When the AsyncCallback method receives the information, it try to write this message in an Excel worksheet.

Everything works ok, but if in the same moment that the method is executed I am editing another cells, the ws.get_Range("A1").Value doesn't work.
Can I resolve it? Is there any other way to set this message in a mandatory way over any other event of the Excel?

```
private void MessageCallBack(IAsyncResult aResult)
{
    try
    {
        byte[] receivedData = new byte[10];
        receivedData = (byte[])aResult.AsyncState;

        ASCIIEncoding aEncoding = new ASCIIEncoding();
        string receivedMessage = aEncoding.GetString(receivedData);

        Worksheet ws = SingletonExcel.getWorksheet();
        ws.get_Range("A1").Value = receivedMessage 
     }
     catch (Exception ex)
     {
         MessageBox.Show("the Cell A1 has not modifed: " + ex.Message);
     }
}
```

Comment: When you say "I am editing other cells" do you mean that the cursor is in the formula-editing bar? When it is, most Excel functions are disabled. You can possibly detect this and wait - and possibly even exit edit mode, but I doubt you'll be able to do anything while Excel is in that mode.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to activate the worksheet before setting the value. I'm not really sure why, but the Excel api sometimes cannot retrieve a value if the object you are using is not active.

```
ws.Activate()
```